# Shouldn't this be a basic feasible solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

[image]
the answer given is that it is a feasible solution, but as the variables are at 0/1 level, isnt it basic too?

Answer (score 0):

You have $4$ constraints but $5$ variables.

To be basic, you need $5$ independent constraints that are active.